# C# File.ReadAllLines not breaking on line feeds

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I have an application that I am building that needs to modify a configuration file.

My problem is that I am not able to read the file in line by line.  I keep geeting the the entire file as a single string.

```
string ConfigTemplate = AEBuildsSPFolderName + "\\Template_BuildReleaseScript.Config";

string[] fileSourceLines = File.ReadAllLines(ConfigTemplate, Encoding.Default);
//Returns the entire file contents into the first array element.

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ConfigTemplate))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
//Returns the entire file contents into the first line read.
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

david

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing the line break character used might not be `\r\n`

When you read your entire file into a single string, try calling `yourString.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` and see if that works for you.

Also since `ReadAllLines()` was just reading into a single string anyway, you could simply use `ReadAllText()`.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Based upon your comments, here is a test code segment I put together...

//Get File Lines
string[] fileSourceLines = File.ReadAllLines(ConfigTemplate, Encoding.Default);

if (fileSourceLines.Length == 1)
{
    string yourString = fileSourceLines[0];
    string[] newSourceLines = yourString.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    //This array still only contains 1 string.
}

newSourceLines array still only contains 1 string.

Any other suggestions :)

Thanks,

david

Answer (score 1):

Your file probably uses `\n` characters (without `\r`) as newlines.