# Convert plain text extracted from table to objects

Tags: c#, text-parsing

Hello I am trying to figure out best possible algorythm parsing plain text to objects here is example of parsed table:

```
Tilte Code quantity price sum
Item1 item1 2 1.50 3.00
Item2 item2 1 3.00 3.00
good
Item3 item3 2 1.00 2.00
```

Objects result should look like :

```
title = Item1, code = item1, quantity = 2, price = 1.50, sum = 3.00

title = Item2 good, code = item2, quantity = 1, price = 3.00, sum = 3.00

title = Item3, code = item3, quantity = 2, price = 1.00, sum = 2.00
```

And so on. The main problem is then title or code contains linebreak. So simple reading by line by line would not work. Have you encountered same problem? Maybe you made some algorythm before and solved this problem. Please share you'r ideas. Waiting for response.

Comment: *"The main problem is then title or code contains linebreak"* - how do you obtain the title now? It's too early to ask for *"best possible algorythm"* before you tried anything.

Comment: How does "good" come into play here? Where in the object should it fit if it isn't aligned to the columns?

Comment: @Jokab good is part of the tilte of Item2

Comment: Here's a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777939/c-sharp-file-readalllines-not-breaking-on-line-feeds

Comment: you can loop through each line, and if a line only contains a title, append it to the title of the previous line

Comment: The field with the newline is *Sum*, not title. Characters in files come one after the other with no knowledge of the layout that some user or appliaction may display them. What you are trying to do *depends* on how the contents are displayed. Don't use such a format if possible. Delimited files *can* contain newlines in the fields, with the rest of the fields appearing in the next line.

Comment: What you ask requires that you parse pairs of lines separately. If the second line doesn't look like a proper field, it may be used as the content of the first field of the previous line. Unfortunately, you have multiple text fields parsing becomes a lot harder

Comment: How to deal with `title = Item2 Item3 item3, ...` ?  I.o.w, you need restrictions on the title fields, and add them to your question here.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this text data is converted from image table and the text layout extracted is allways the same. You can ignore header values. The only way I am thinking about is reading lines by line and column then compare results which row has less data and which data is appended in new line. After requirements are collected append title or code of prieviuos row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your data excerpt represents a golden standard, this should do the trick:

```
// String[] data = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt");

String[] data = 
{ 
    "Tilte Code quantity price sum",
    "Item1 item1 2 1.50 3.00",
    "Item2 item2 1 3.00 3.00",
    "good",
    "Item3 item3 2 1.00 2.00"
};

CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
List<dynamic> objects = new List<dynamic>();
String title = String.Empty;

foreach (String line in data.Skip(1))
{
    String[] parts = line.Split(new [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (parts.Length == 1)
    {
        title = line;
        continue;
    }

    String titleItem = parts[0];

    if (title != String.Empty)
        titleItem += " " + title;

    objects.Add(new
    {
        Title = titleItem,
        Code = parts[1],
        Quantity = Int32.Parse(parts[2]),
        Price = Single.Parse(parts[3], ci),
        Sum = Single.Parse(parts[4], ci),
    });
}

foreach (dynamic obj in objects)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[ENTRY]");
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Title);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Code);       
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Quantity);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Price);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Sum);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output:

```
[ENTRY]
Item1
item1
2
1,5
3

[ENTRY]
Item2
item2
1
3
3

[ENTRY]
Item3 good
item3
2
1
2
```

You can try a live demo visiting [this link](http://rextester.com/JCZ96415).

Comment: Thank you for very detailed answer!